# Prolog gives ERROR: Undefined procedure: utterance/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Tags: prolog

utterance(X) :- sentence(X, [ ]).

sentence(Start, End) :-
nounphrase(Start, Rest, Number),
verbphrase(Rest, End, Number).

nounphrase([Noun | End], End, Number) :-
noun(Noun, Number).
nounphrase([Article, Noun | End], End, Number) :-
noun(Noun, Number), article(Article, Number).

verbphrase([Verb | End], End, Number) :-
verb(Verb, Number).
verbphrase([Verb | Rest], End, Number) :-
verb(Verb, Number), nounphrase(Rest, End, _).

article(a, singular).
article(the, singular).
article(the, plural).

noun(man, singular).
noun(men, plural).
noun(woman, singular).
noun(women, plural).
noun(dog, singular).
noun(dogs, plural).

verb(likes, singular).
verb(like, plural).
verb(bites, singular).
verb(bite, plural).

ERROR: Undefined procedure: utterance/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that you have not loaded the source code. Save it in a file named e.g. `grammar.pl`. Then start your Prolog compiler (it seems that you're using SWI-Prolog from the text of the error message) and change the current working directory to the directory where you saved the source file and use the following query to load the file:

```
?- [grammar].
```

Alternatively, use the full path to the source file between single quotes:

```
?- ['/foo/bar/grammar'].
```

Then you should be able to call the `utterance/1` predicate without getting that error.